# Rails 3 ActiveRecord: "OR-ing" together multiple bools

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord object `RaceCarDriver`.  Three of the fields are boolean: `is_from_texas`, `is_from_arkansas`, and `is_from_indiana`.  In the user search interface, the user could select neither to see all results, select `is_from_texas` to see only drivers from Texas, or select `is_from_texas` and `is_from_indiana` to see all drivers from one of those states.

Now, I know this example is a bit contrived, but I wanted to avoid the complexity of the actual app.

My best attempt is along these lines:

```
@drivers = RaceCarDriver.select('name').
where(params[:check_texas] == 0 || :is_from_texas => params[:check_texas]).
where(params[:check_arkansas] == 0 || :is_from_arkansas => params[:check_arkansas]).
where(params[:check_indiana] == 0 || :is_from_indiana => params[:check_indiana])
```

However, this `ANDS` the chained `where` clauses together, making it so that if Texas and Indiana were both checked a driver would have to be from both states.

Again, I know this is contrived.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@drivers = RaceCarDriver.select('name')
@drivers = @drivers.where(:is_from_texas => params[:check_texas]) if params[:check_texas]
@drivers = @drivers.where(:is_from_arkansas => params[:check_arkansas]) if params[:check_arkansas]
@drivers = @drivers.where(:is_from_indiana => params[:check_indiana]) if params[:check_indiana]
```

**EDIT**

Solution 1:

```
where_options = { :is_from_texas => params[:check_texas],
                  :is_from_arkansas => params[:check_arkansas],
                  :is_from_indiana => params[:check_indiana] }.select{|k,v| v.present? }
where_conditions = where_options.map{|k,v| "#{k} = #{v}"}.join(" OR ")
@drivers = RaceCarDriver.select('name').where(where_conditions)
```

Solution 2:

```
@scoped_drivers = RaceCarDriver.select('name')
@drivers = []
@drivers << @scoped_drivers.where(:is_from_texas => params[:check_texas]) if params[:check_texas]
@drivers << @scoped_drivers.where(:is_from_arkansas => params[:check_arkansas]) if params[:check_arkansas]
@drivers << @scoped_drivers.where(:is_from_indiana => params[:check_indiana]) if params[:check_indiana]
@drivers.flatten!
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  But, unfortunately this still "ANDS" the items in the "where" clause together rather than "OR"-ing them.

Comment: Solution 1 is a very elegant way to do this.  Especially considering there are about 15 of these in my real project.

Answer (score 1):

```
RaceCarDriver.select('name').
where("is_from_texas = ? OR is_from_arkansas = ? OR is_from_indiana = ?",params[:is_from_texas],params[:is_from_arkansas],params[:is_from_indiana])
```

Comment: I am not sure if `nil` is the same as `false`